# React Native Navigation v2

Tags: react-native

How to install ReactNative Navigation v2 , Installed several time with react native latest version and with 0.55.0 as per documentation but every time getting new new errors , could some one help me for installed that, but it is working with

---

"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
        "react-native": "0.49.5",
        "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.277"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*npm install react-navigation^2.0.0 --save*

Comment: Just a silly question. v2.5.2 is defeinitely V2 right ?  The documentation for RNN is all over the place. I am facing an issue with RNN and wanted to make sure that I am indeed using V2